# What could cause a delay in page rendering in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-vista

Whenever I search for something using Google Chrome's address bar, before the search results appear, I get this:

[image]

It is there only for a moment and then I get my results. This thing only happens with Google Chrome (not with firefox, I checked).

**Does anyone know why I am getting this? Is this a bug?**

Version:

```
Google Chrome   5.0.322.2 (Official Build 38810) unknown
WebKit  533.1
V8  2.1.0.1
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) 
    AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.322.2 Safari/533.1
```

---

As suggested by Bavi_H,

> If you go to a page of Google search
>   results and look at the HTML source,
>   right after the opening body tag
>   there's a textarea with
>   style=display:none. It appears that
>   Chrome browser is experiencing a
>   momentary delay while rendering the
>   page and I am seeing that textarea
>   before Chrome applies the display:none
>   style.

**Now, what could be causing this page rendering delay?**

The extensions I am using are:

- Chrome Lock
- Facebook Photo Zoom
- Google Dictionary
- Google Quick Scroll
- Readability Redux
- Session Buddy
- SmoothScroll

Comment: Seems like he's showing the result box before he has fetched all results...sorry, no idea on that.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed ?

Comment: @TiNS: yes, but none that relates to the search functionality. Is there some specific one that is known to cause this?

Comment: I had this exact issue on FF actually. It was AdBlock.

Comment: If you go to a page of Google search results and look at the HTML source, right after the opening `body` tag there's a `textarea` with `style=display:none`. It appears your Chrome browser is experiencing a momentary delay while rendering the page and you're seeing that textarea before Chrome applies the display:none style. So the next part of the question might be: What could be causing a page rendering delay?

Comment: If you disable all of your extensions (temporarily), do you still experience this delay and multi-line textbox?

Comment: Does it relate at all to the number of tabs you have open, and the amount of free ram you have?

Comment: Technically, a lot of extensions do affect all pages. For some extensions, like the scrolling ones, they run their javascript code on all pages. This is why the installation process warns you that they could steal your passwords or do other malicious things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use Chromium and developer tools to profile the culprit you will need to disable extensions to check which extension is causing the delay. To do this quick, don't do them one by one but disable the half each time. This way you only visit the extensions three times to check eight extensions... Good luck!